# Dynamic array size in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic-arrays

Some time ago I used Visual Studio, and there was a function *_msize* for counting size of dynamic array.
Now I'm trying to do the same in Xcode. I've read somewhere, that for that purpose in Xcode I have to use *malloc_size* function, but it returns something strange.

```
char* mass = new char[6]{"HELLO"};
    
    cout << "malloc_size(mass)               " << malloc_size(mass)<<endl;
    cout << "sizeof(mass)                    " << sizeof(mass)<<endl;
    cout << "sizeof(mass[0])                 " << sizeof(mass[0])<<endl;
    cout << "malloc_size(mass)/sizeof(mass)  " << malloc_size(mass)/sizeof(mass)<< endl;
```

Output:

```
malloc_size(mass)               16
sizeof(mass)                    8
sizeof(mass[0])                 1
malloc_size(mass)/sizeof(mass)  2
```

Could anybody suggest something what behaves similar to *_msize*?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why can't you use e.g. `std::string` for strings and `std::vector` for other "dynamic arrays"? Have you tried to fine documentation for [`malloc_size`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc_size.3.html) or otherwise done some research about it?

Comment: `malloc()` can (and likely does) allocate more bytes than requested. The output of `_msize()` is the actual allocated size, not the requested size. This is even described in Apple's [`malloc_size()` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc_size.3.html): "*The `malloc_size()` function returns the size of the memory block that backs the allocation pointed to by ptr. **The memory block size is always at least as large as the allocation it backs, and may be larger**.*" `malloc_size()` is doing the same as `_msize()`.

Comment: Instead of "similar", you could go for "better". For example, containers that track their size for you. (I'm using "works on any platform" as one of my criteria for "better". YMMV.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm studying now, and I'm not allowed to use strings and vectors. In VisualStudio I used `_msize(mass)/sizeof(mass[0])` in order to define number of arrays' elements in order to iterate it through the loop, but in Xcode i stuck...

Comment: You used _msize improperly. `_msize(mass)/sizeof(mass[0])` does not return number of array elements, due to the same reason **The memory block size is always at least as large as the allocation it backs, and may be larger."**

Comment: Even if the functions returned the allocated size exactly, it could still lead to problem if not all of the memory is initialized. Take for example something like `char* str = new[20]; strcpy(str, "foo");`. Now four "elements" of the allocated memory is initialized, but what about the remaining 16? They will have an *indeterminate* value, and using those values will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: If you are studying, you shall not use any non standard function like `_msize` or `malloc_size`. They are for advanced uses only, like profiling memory usage.